# SQL Cursor with condition in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a cursor where i am passing a flag and inside that cursor ,i am using following condition

```
cursor abc (c_flag ) 
IS
   select 1  
     from pqr  p 
    where p.c1 = CASE c_flag ='Y' 
                    THEN p.c1
                    ELSE IS NOT NULL 
                 END
```

Now the issue is that the ELSE case won't work for me since it should be written like `p.c1 IS NOT NULL`, rather  than p.c1 = IS NOT NULL.

I think you got what i want to do, if `c_flag` is yes, I'll take all the records, and if not then pick all not null records.
I am using Oracle as RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cursor abc (c_flag ) 
IS
   select 1  
     from pqr  p 
    where 1 = CASE 
               when c_flag ='Y'      then 1
               when p.c1 IS NOT NULL then 1
               else 0
              END
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `OR` for this

```
SELECT 1
FROM   pqr p
WHERE  c_flag = 'Y'
        OR p.c1 IS NOT NULL
```